# SharePoint 2010 stripping shape and coords from <area> tags

Tags: html, sharepoint-2010

We have site in Sharepoint 2007 (WSS) that we're migrating to Sharepoint 2010 (Foundation).  One of the pages on the site consists of an image with links mapped via  and  tags -- i.e.:

```
<map name="name">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,10,15" href="http://somesite.com/" />
</map>
```

When I try to get the tags above into a 2010 page, it strips off the shape and coords attributes, leaving me with:

```
<map name="name">
<area href="http://somesite.com/" />
</map>
```

I've tried a Wiki page, a Wiki page with a Content Editor webpart and a webpart page with a Content editor webpart -- all with the same result adding this via Edit HTML Source.

Any help or suggestions much appreciated -- thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use SharePoint Designer + "Advanced Mode" Editing.

Comment: Sharepoint designer resolved the issue for now -- we just have to remember not to edit that page in any way through the browser or it strips them again.  :)  Nice feature.

Answer (score 1):

Which browser(s) are you seeing this with? I've experienced the same thing that you describe with a Publishing site with IE7.

As the same user accessing the same site via IE8 I can edit the source and it preserves the Shape and Coords attributes.

Not very satisfactory as it makes it hard to trust future edits not mangling the page but meanwhile this has got around the problem for me.

Comment: We're stuck on IE7 as a corporate decision right now, but will try IE8 (or IE 37, based on our upgrade speed).  Thanks.