# Can I stop Sharepoint's RichHtmlField stripping data-* attributes?

Tags: html, sharepoint, wysiwyg

I've got a page layout with a PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField inside. In use, if I add some HTML with data-* attributes, e.g. a Twitter share button:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en">Tweet</a>
```

Then save the changes, the `data-en` attribute goes missing.

Is there a way I can stop them being stripped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the answer in the following post help you? It suggests using SharePoint Designer to edit the HTML.

[SharePoint 2010 stripping shape and coords from <area> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779951/sharepoint-2010-stripping-shape-and-coords-from-area-tags)